# Laravel 5.5 Resources Customize show($id) method

Tags: laravel, api, routes, postman

All!!

I'm trying to develop an API in Laravel 5.5 and I really stuck in this point:

I have this Routes:

```
Route::get('products', 'ProductController@index'); ==> Works OK
Route::get('product/{id}', 'ProductController@show'); ==> Works OK
Route::get('product/{barcode}', 'ProductController@productByEan'); ==> Fail
```

With these methods:

```
public function index()
{
  $product = Product::paginate(15);
  return ProductResource::collection($product);
}

public function show($id)
{
  $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
  return new ProductResource($product);
}
```

Following is the same logic I created show method using the id to get my product and it is working fine, but when I create a new method called productByEan to obtain a product using the EAN13 (barcode) instead the id with this method
(Using postman with this URL: http://ws.barcode.primerbit.com/api/product/9440396613933):

```
public function productByEan($barcode)
{   
    $response =  Product::where('barcode',$barcode);
    return new ProductResource($response);
}
```

Obtain "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found"
I don't know what happened, so if there anyone could help me I'll be very thankful.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Thank's a lot !! I' ll try all, to see what's happen, but a little detail that i omited was tha te product id it' The pk but barcode is another field on The same table. Can i use show method with a non pk field?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the `product/{id}` route, `product/{barcode}` will never be executed. So, change it to something like:

```
product/barcode/{barcode}
```

Or you could use different verb like POST instead of GET for this route:

```
Route::post('product/{barcode}', 'ProductController@productByEan');
```

You could also try to change order of these two routes and add [regular expression constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints):

```
Route::get('product/{barcode}', 'ProductController@productByEan')->where('barcode', '[0-9]{13}');    
Route::get('product/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation as to what will match your `{id}` in the `Route::get('product/{id}', 'ProductController@show');` route.

This means that ANYTHING matching `product/*` will be using the `ProductController@show` method.

You can try this for yourself by switching the 2 routes. i.e.

```
Route::get('product/{barcode}', 'ProductController@productByEan');
Route::get('product/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
```

As you will see all urls using EANs will work now but the id's will stop working.

To prevent the "all variables matching this route" behaviour you could limit the scope of either the ID or barcode, since barcodes have readily available limitations you could most easily use that.

Try switching your routes and changing the barcode route to:

```
Route::get('product/{barcode}', 'ProductController@productByEan')->where('barcode', '[0-9]{13}');
```

This will make sure the barcode MUST match a 13 digit long number. Any other number or string will not match and thus be passed along to your other route based on ID.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution for this issue, the error wasn't in the rules, actually the i didn't change any rule, the problem was my productByEan() method in ProductController, because this method is refencing to a ProductResource, so when i tried to create a new instance of ProductResource eloquent could not get the object properties and threw the follow exception:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$id

Where $id is the first property in the ProductResource:

```
 public function toArray($request)
{
   // return parent::toArray($request);

   return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'barcode' => $this->barcode,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'price' => $this->price,
        'currency'=> $this->currency

   ];

}`
```

So, the solution was change ProductByEan method from this:

```
 public function productByEan($barcode)
{   
    $response =  Product::where('barcode',$barcode)->get();

     return  new ProductResource::collection($response);
}
```

To this:

```
 public function productByEan($barcode)
{   
    $response =  Product::where('barcode',$barcode)->get();

     return  ProductResource::collection($response);
}
```

And It works!

Thanks a lot for your help!!